# Автомат однорукий бандит

Tags: python, numpy

Всем привет! Пытаюсь прописать код для "Однорукого бандита". Беда в том, что не могу понять как написать условия для выигрыша при выпадении результатов:
**7
*77
*00
**0
Прошу сильно не кидать тапками. Только начинаю)
И есть ли более лаконичные способы сделать это?

```
import numpy as np
trials = 1000   
success0 = 0    
success1 = 0
success2 = 0
success3 = 0
success4 = 0

for i in range(trials):
    random_score = np.random.randint(0, 1000)    
    if random_score == 777:
        success0 += 1
    elif random_score == 999:
        success1 += 1
    elif random_score == 555:
        success2 += 1
    elif random_score == 333:
        success3 += 1
    elif random_score == 111:
        success4 += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте остаток от деления на 10 и на 100, например:

```py
# **7
elif random_score % 10 == 7:

# *77
elif random_score % 109 == 77:

# *00
elif random_score % 100 == 0:

# **0
elif random_score % 10 == 0:
```

Comment: Премного благодарен. Не был в курсе про остаток от деления. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой. Результат после цикла % 100 == 77 всегда равняется 0. То есть никогда не "выпадает".
Думается мне, что это реакция после % 10 == 7. Не понимаю как решить проблему.

Comment: А, ну сначала нужно на более длинные комбинации проверять, конечно, а потом уже на более короткие, да.